# Which process uses what pages?

Tags: linux, rhel, memory

I have memory fragmented on my Linux system. Is there a way to find out what pages (in terms of order) and how many of them are used by each process running?

Comment: you mean open files by each process...`lsof`

Comment: @SivaPrasath, I mean memory pages used by long-running processes. For instance, the process has memory cache, caching some strings with different length (from 4Kb to 128Kb). Is there a way to find out how many memory pages does the process uses for each page order? In my case I don't know what process fragments memory... As far as I know `lsof` shows the amount of files opened by process.

Comment: Do you mean how a process uses its virtual memory? Or the physical memory backing that virtual memory? And, is there some practical issue   with measurable effects related to this?

Comment: @ilkkachu, I think, physical memory. My system is suffering from memory fragmentation, that's why I'm asking. I've posted a question here some time ago.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440155/memory-fragmentation-on-rhel7

Answer (score 1):

You can get information from `/proc/<PID>/maps`.

Example:

```
$ cat /proc/3618/maps 
00400000-005ce000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 78541      /usr/sbin/<service>
007cd000-00811000 rw-p 001cd000 fd:00 78541      /usr/sbin/<service>
```

If you are concerned by pages which are really in RAM, use [mincore](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mincore) & [msync](http://linux.die.net/man/2/msync)